# Take names from JSON array and display first character in Listview

Tags: json, api, listview, indexing, flutter

I have a list view of projects who all have members assigned to them, I want to display these members in a Futurebuilder with a Listview.builder and I want to return a CircleAvatar with the first letter of the names like: 'H' - 'S' ...

I have tried to do this but I get the letter 'H' in all the cells. I want it to be like: 'H' and 'S' - For hugo, and studentone!

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureBuilderJSON extends StatefulWidget {
  FutureBuilderJSON({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _FutureBuilderJSONState createState() => _FutureBuilderJSONState();
}

class _FutureBuilderJSONState extends State<FutureBuilderJSON> {
  Future<List<Project>> _getProjects() async {
    var data = await http.get(
        "http://studieplaneraren.pythonanywhere.com/api/projects/hugo/?format=json");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body); //an array of json objects
    List<Project> allProjects = [];
    for (var JData in jsonData) {
      Project project = Project(
        JData["id"],
        JData["title"],
        JData["description"],
        JData["deadline"],
        JData["subject"],
        JData["days_left"],
        JData["users"],
      );
      allProjects.add(project);
    }

    return allProjects;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 8, right: 8),
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
        future: _getProjects(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var users = snapshot.data[index].users;
              String username =
                  users != null ? users[0]['username'] : 'Default';
              var oneChar = username.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
              return CircleAvatar(
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(oneChar),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Project {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String deadline;
  final String subject;
  final String days_left;
  final List<dynamic> users;

  Project(
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.deadline,
    this.subject,
    this.days_left,
    this.users,
  );
}

class User {
  final String username;
  final String fullname;
  User(this.username, this.fullname);
}
```

JSON

```
[
{
    "id": 81,
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        },
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        }
    ],
    "title": "test med teacher chat",
    "description": "This project does not have a description.",
    "subject": "No subject",
    "deadline": "2019-01-06",
    "days_left": "109 days ago",
    "overview_requests": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "user": {
                "username": "hugo",
                "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
            },
            "group": 81
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 83,
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "title": "A ducking project",
    "description": "Hej nu har du din ändrade beskrivning!",
    "subject": "No subject",
    "deadline": "2019-01-09",
    "days_left": "106 days ago",
    "overview_requests": []
},
{
    "id": 86,
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "title": "tettestdsfsdf",
    "description": "sdfsadfasdfasdfsadf",
    "subject": "No subject",
    "deadline": "2019-01-09",
    "days_left": "106 days ago",
    "overview_requests": []
}
]
```

[Here is a picture of the APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aHzG.png)

[Here is a screenshot of how It looks now! with the row implemented!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0QE2.png)

HERE IS THE CARD / UI

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getProjects(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
             return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
        );
      } else
        return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EveryProjectPage(
                                snapshot.data[index],
                                snapshot.data[index].id,
                              )));
                },
                child: Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 270,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //TOP PART
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.account_circle,
                                  color: Colors.cyan,
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.more_vert,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                              ),
                              DisplayPercentageLinearly(
                                  snapshot.data[index].id)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        //CIRCLE AVATARS
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 15, left: 12, right: 8),
                            height: 40,
                            child: FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
                                future: _getProjects(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                    return Container(
                                        width: 20,
                                        height: 20,
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount:
                                        snapshot.data[index].users.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var users =
                                          snapshot.data[index].users;

                                      if (users == null) {
                                        return makeAvatar('?');
                                      }

                                      return Row(
                                        children: users
                                            .map<CircleAvatar>((e) =>
                                                makeAvatar(e['username']))
                                            .toList(),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                })),

                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 75, left: 20),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                              "You have ${snapshot.data[index].days_left} days left"),
                        ),

                        //TEXT PART
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 15, top: 6),
                          child: Text(
                            "${snapshot.data[index].title[0].toString().toUpperCase()}"
                                "${snapshot.data[index].title.toString().substring(1)}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
    });
  }
} 

class DisplayPercentageLinearly extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  DisplayPercentageLinearly(this.id);

  @override
  _DisplayPercentageLinearlyState createState() =>
  _DisplayPercentageLinearlyState(this.id);
}

   class _DisplayPercentageLinearlyState extends       State<DisplayPercentageLinearly> {
  //ID
  final int id;

   _DisplayPercentageLinearlyState(this.id);

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return LinearPercentIndicator(
  width: 175,
  lineHeight: 13,
  percent: 0.2,
  backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
  progressColor: Colors.amber,
  center: Text(
    "",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
   );
    }
}
```

Comment: The first username in every project is `hugo`. Admittedly the first project has a second username, studentone. But since you have just one row in your list view per project, and are taking the first project username from each one, you should expect 3 rows each with an `H` avatar.

Comment: How do I change it to displaying the first letter in every username?

Comment: How many times should `H` appear? Once or 3 times? Either way, you need to pre-process the list of `Project`s to extract a list of usernames. Iterate over the list of projects, and then in an inner loop over `users` either adding each username to a list (duplicates allowed) or a `Set` which will swallow duplicates. Then use that list to populate your listview. (It's tricky to understand what you want, as you haven't specified exactly how you'd like to deal with project 81, which has two users and the other projects that have just one.)

Comment: So I have updated the JSON now, maybe you can see that there is three projects, these will be displayed in a future builder with a listview.builder. Inside every cell there will be another listview displaying a CircleAvatar with the first letter of the users that in that particular project. So the first one: 'H' and 'S', the second one 'H', the third one 'H'

Comment: I have also linked a picture that shows how the app looks, this is project management so the CircleAvatars are the users assigned to that particular project!

Comment: Just posted the card! :)

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question, I reformulate my answer to actually answer your question.

## New answer:

If you want to iterate through the `var users` you can use the `map()` function if the `var users` is a list.

#### You can use this:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  var users = snapshot.data[index].users;
  return Column( // It doesn't need to be Column, it can be any widget with a children attribute.
    children: users.map((var user) {
      return CircleAvatar(
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(user['username'].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
},
```

#### Explanation

Let me explain the code: We need to return a widget with a children attribute, because as children we return a `List` with the `CircularAvatar()` widgets for each user. In this case we use a `Column()` widget.

In the children attribute we call `users.map()`, this will iterate through every single user inside users. `map()` takes a callback function, that callback function will execute for each item inside the users `List`. And that callback function takes an argument that is the item of the `List`.

Inside the callback function we can now return a `CircularAvatar()` and as child we return a `Text()` widget. As parameter we call `user['username']` to get the username of the current user at the iteration. Then we call `substring(0,1)` to get the first letter of the username. And finally we call `toUpperCase()` to make sure that the letter is uppercase.

#### Full code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureBuilderJSON extends StatefulWidget {
  FutureBuilderJSON({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _FutureBuilderJSONState createState() => _FutureBuilderJSONState();
}

class _FutureBuilderJSONState extends State<FutureBuilderJSON> {
  Future<List<Project>> _getProjects() async {
    var data = await http.get(
        "http://studieplaneraren.pythonanywhere.com/api/projects/hugo/?format=json");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body); //an array of json objects
    List<Project> allProjects = [];
    for (var JData in jsonData) {
      Project project = Project(
        JData["id"],
        JData["title"],
        JData["description"],
        JData["deadline"],
        JData["subject"],
        JData["days_left"],
        JData["users"],
      );
      allProjects.add(project);
    }

    return allProjects;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 8, right: 8),
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
        future: _getProjects(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var users = snapshot.data[index].users;
              return Column(
                children: users.map((var user) {
                  return CircleAvatar(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(user['username'].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### *Hope I understood right now and that this is helpful for you.*

Comment: Thanks but it still displays just a 'H' in every cell. I want it to display the users that are working on the project. In the case of this project, it should be 'H' and 'S' for Hugo and Studentone :)

Answer (score -1):

var users = snapshot.data[index].users;
give you the list of the users, you should iterate gain over those to build the list, you're just getting the first item of the list.

```
String username = ... users[0]['username'] ...
```